How to keep the Image in square shape in any screen dimensions
I am stuck in image dimension change on-screen responsiveness.
I have 4 products with images in one row. I wanted Images in square shape so I gave them the fixed height and auto width. they were looking good, but when I changed the screen dimensions/responsiveness, they ignored the fixed height and malfunctions.
Full-screen
In full screen, there is the default width assigned to each product of 25%. The images look square.

Different smaller dimensions.
In different screen dimensions, they do not follow the square shape.


What do I need?
I need them in a square shape, regardless of the screen dimensions, for example, if they were 300x300 on full screen, they should be at least 200x200 on small screen, and so on.
Is there any way we can calculate dynamically, the dimensions of images according to the the screen dimensions in CSS?
Code


/* css here */
<div class="bee-col-items" style="width:25%">
  <div class="bee-product-inner" style="border: 1px">
    <div class="bee-product-image" style="position:relative; height:332px; width:auto;"> <img style="object-fit:fill; width:100%; height:100%; " src="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I need your help regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@Paulie_D my issue is with the images, that's why I have to show the theme here for better understanding. I have removed the code from the images. now there are only images in the above images. I am here to seek very important help. Please upvote again. thanks.

Pictures of your images is OK but the HTML and CSS would help here re: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Start by NOT putting in style attributes in the elements such as remove style="position:relative; height:332px; width:auto;"  Use proper CSS

@MarkSchultheiss I have removed the code from the images. Please recheck.

I think you missed my point - code as CODE is needed but not as an image

@MarkSchultheiss The inline style is just for better understanding. In real, it is in a CSS file.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I am not clear exactly what you need. You have given the parent div of each img a fixed height. Do you always want the image to have that height (and therefore that width in order to be square)? I suspect not since not all the images will show on a narrow screen. Please describe in more detail what is required.

I created a snippet with what you posted but it is missing CSS and in need of being a more representable example of what you have here.

You could use css grid or flex, and use aspect-ratio and object-fit to display the images as squares regardless of their size.
Here's an example:


.img-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1720886073981-f975d3dc93f8">
        <img src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1720886073981-f975d3dc93f8">
        <img src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1720886073981-f975d3dc93f8">
        <img src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1720886073981-f975d3dc93f8">
    </div>
</body>
</html>




Use the combination of CSS properties, such as aspect-ratio and media queries to resolve this issue.
1. Aspect-ratio of 1:1 to maintain the square shape: With this CSS property HTML element is going to be square no matter what size appears on the screen.
2. Media Queries: Use media queries to adjust the size of the images based on different screen widths.
This will ensure that your images maintain a square shape and adjust their size dynamically based on the screen dimensions.

Doing the aspect ratio trick with css will work for this. For a square using aspect ratio 1:1 is good. See below.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.aspect-ratio {
  width: 200px; /* set any width and it will maintain 1:1 (aka square) */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.aspect-ratio::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%; /* aspect ratio 1:1 */
}

.aspect-ratio img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
<div class="aspect-ratio">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="Placeholder Image" />
</div>



padding-top is the main one for the aspect ratio. if set to 100% it will mean that for width of a length, height will also be that length, if you change the 100% to something else, you maintain a different ratio.
